# Using a poset or directed graph as input for a neural network

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, posets, machine-learning, directed-graphs

I'm not sure if this is the right community to post this in but I would appreciate any help. As the title states, I'm trying to train a neural network using some unconventional input. I'm wondering if anyone has any experience or has read any papers that involve using a partially ordered set or alternatively a directed graph as an input for a neural network? Is there a way something like a directed graph can be effectively embedded as a vector? If so, I would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thanks

Comment: Your question might be a better fit for: https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Neural networks are not my area, but couldn't you use an incidence matrix or something?

Comment: If we have a graph with 1 million nodes, then the incidence matrix will have 1 trillion entries, and each row that corresponds to a node on the directed graph will have 1 million entries. Neural networks do not like dealing with very long vectors of variable length. A better option would be to associate the vertices in a digraph with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in such a way so that similar vertices are associated with similar vectors. Various graph embeddings like Node2Vec exist. But it is probably a good idea to get a handle of word embeddings before going to graph embeddings.

Comment: It seems like poset embeddings should be used in natural language processing. In natural language processing, we typically split text into tokens such as "The oversimplification of transactions causes suffering." becoming ' The' ' oversimplification' ' of' ' transactions' ' causes' ' suffering', but we can also tokenize this text like 'The' ' 
 over' 'simpli' 'fication' ' of' ' trans' 'actions' ' causes' ' suffer' 'ing'. Since there is typically multiple ways to split text into tokens, these tokens should be partially ordered, so we need a poset embedding to represent this.

Answer (score 6):

This is most definitely NOT the right spot to ask such a question, thought it is a good one.
I happen to dabble precisely with these things in these days, for my own work and research, so I think I can help you.

The first thing you have to look up is **GRAPH DEEP LEARNING**:
[here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.12693)  is an excellent survey for this new area of **Deep Neural Networks**.

There are also several libraries you can use to do experiments and to get some tutorials, for instance **DGL** and **StellarGraph** (both Python).

Now, as to your question: you can either follow the simple suggestion by Todd Trimble, which in fact goes a long way, or you also have some ready-made  data structures which encode whatever you need from your graph (directed, undirected, weighted, property based, etc) and then the libraries I mentioned will provide you suitable layers to handle your use case.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!